# C# Handle two methods with same lock differently

Tags: c#, locking, mutex, readerwriterlockslim

I have a class with two methods (one instance):

```
public class Example
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (someCondition)
            Connect();

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

It is `DoSomething` allowed to be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.
However, if `Connect` is called, no thread is allowed to enter `DoSomething` and vice versa, so `Connect` and `DoSomething` are mutually exclusive.
`DoSomething` is called more often than `Connect`.

My first idea was to use `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, however, when `DomeSomething` aquires the reader lock and needs to call `Connect` itself, it cannot aquire the writer lock in `Connect`.

What synchronization pattern is most appropriate to achieve this goal?

Comment: The lock you want to use supports upgrading to write lock, so you may be able to use it.

Comment: Entering the write lock throws a LockRecursionException: 'The current thread has entered read mode and doesn't already own a write lock, so trying to enter the lock in write mode would create the possibility of a deadlock.' If I use an `UpgradableReadLock` instead of a `ReadLock` multiple threads cannot enter

Comment: Did you use EnterUpgradeableReadLock?    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The docs for `EnterUpgradeableReadLock` state: 'Only one thread can enter upgradeable mode at any given time.' So this is no replacement for the read lock. Using `EnterUpgradeableReadLock` would prevent multiple threads to access `DoSomething` at the same time.

Comment: You can't ask for `Connect` and `DoSomething` to be mutually exclusive and then expect calling one from the other to work. What are you trying to achieve?